# Take first match of one of these in a Bash script

Tags: linux, bash, grep, sed

I'm making a bash script for reading files in /`usr/share/applications` to generate a menu for [IceWM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IceWM). Here is some of my code:

```
file = nm-connection-editor.desktop
name = $((grep -m 1 "Name=" $file) | sed 's/Name=//g')
icon = $ ((grep Icon= $file) | sed 's/Icon=//g')
execu = $ ((grep -m 1 Exec= $file) | sed 's/Exec=//g')
commandline = "prog $name $icon $execu"
cate = $(grep -m 1 Categories $file)
echo $cate result in:
Categories=GNOME;GTK;Settings;X-GNOME-NetworkSettings;

if [ $(echo $cate |grep Network) ]; then echo $commandline >> menu.Network; fi
if [ $(echo $cate |grep Settings) ]; then echo $commandline >> menu.Settings; fi
```

The problem is that `$commandline` appears in both categories.

I want it to appear only in Settings

I think in a list of words: Games Network Utility Settings Office System...

and select (from `$cate`) the closest to the beginning of the line, but how?

Comment: Can you use an `elif` for your Second `if` instead?  That way `NetworkSettings` won't match both lines

Comment: The code as provided has syntax errors - the spaces between assignments, lack of spaces before brackets in if statements. Presumably due to an error pasting it in, but it makes more work for others to test it.

Comment: Try modifying this section in the 2nd to last line from |grep Network to |grep Network | grep -v "$commandline"

Comment: Can provide the specific input (what values you get in the initial assignments in your code) and provide what you want the output to be (exactly). The clarification you've provided made me understand it less; I think there is a language barrier.  Also, if you are running the code as is you will get some bad data-the spaces need to be removed eg use: icon=$(( ...  Not: icon = $ (( ...

Comment: Actually, disregard the fix regarding spaces. The entire statement is flawed. Its going to try to execute the result from the grep, among many other issues.

Answer (score 1):

Your sequential `if` statements look like a more natural fit for `case`:

```
case "$cate" in
    *Network*)
        echo $commandline >> menu.Network
        ;;
    *Settings*)
        echo $commandline >> menu.Settings
        ;;
esac
```